# Export Trello board to CSV/XLS including custom fields and labels

Tags: trello, trello-cards, export

I've got a Trello board which uses the Custom fields power up and labels.

I'd like to export a CSV or XLS file of all the cards with their custom fields and labels included.

I've explored various ways to do this, but so far haven't been able to find a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

As of January 2017, there isn't currently a way to export the custom fields data via the UI.

Luckily, it *is* accessible via the API and a call to the pluginData resource [/cards/[cardId]/pluginData](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#get-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-pluginData).

I've thrown together a small project that gets you halfway to where you want to be. You can check it out here: https://gomix.com/#!/project/export-trello-board-example

This is a small node app that will give you a JSON response containing a card's ID, name, and pluginData (if it has any). You can extend this and add in any fields you want!

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you. FWIW the API is documented [here](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#get-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-pluginData) and don't do as I did and prepend the board ID into the URL.

Comment: @drstevok. The documentation you linked is for retrieving the `pluginData` for a card. Only a valid card ID will work for that resource. If you want to get the `pluginData` for a board, you will want to use [this resource](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/board#get-1-boards-board-id-pluginData). It will take a board ID and give you the `pluginData` for that board.

Answer (score 0):

From Trello's help page: http://help.trello.com/article/747-exporting-data-from-trello-1

> Export to Excel / Spreadsheets
>
> If you need spreadsheet support, boards exported with Business Class include CSV exports which can be imported in to spreadsheet applications like Excel. Each user in a Business Class team has an option on the board to export to CSV.

Comment: Thanks, but using that feature in business class dosnt include any of the custom feilds data in the spreadsheet.

Comment: They describe a solution here, may be worth giving it a try: http://help.trello.com/article/828-getting-custom-data-from-trello-into-a-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Trello Add-in for Excel here https://extracts.io/trello to import directly from Excel.

It imports Cards, Board and Teams. It will also import labels and custom fields.

It saves which boards you've selected, so if you create any charts, summaries or pivot tables, you can just go in and click "Import" to refresh the data.

Disclaimer: I made it!

Answer (score -1):

Zapier has pre-built zaps that let you select custom fields to export to a Google Sheet, etc.