# Can I indicate from which customer a Trello task is for?

Tags: trello

I'm trying to use Trello for support system administration.

I have a software company and I want to load my tasks in Trello, but I need a simple option that lets me select from what customer an issue originates. This is 
so in the future I can filter issues by customer and see the history.

Is there a way to do this in Trello?

Comment: I closed this question as it looks like a support ticket, not as a practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask], [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)

Answer (score 0):

You can identify them a customer by adding a label to each card, for example. There's tools that can help you automate this. If you can share more information, it'll be easier to help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [custom fields](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/98436/export-trello-board-to-csv-xls-including-custom-fields-and-labels) or labels for this.

Using labels means you can assign them very quickly by hovering your mouse over a card and pressing the number buttons. They are also part of the free version of Trello meaning you can use them even if you aren't yet paying for Trello. You can also easily filter your Trello board by label, which you say is a key requirement for you.

Using custom fields has a few advantages and disadvantages. Firstly, you can keep your labels set up a lot tidier if you don't use lots of labels for different things (ie, customer, request type, urgency, etc). You can use a custom dropdown field if you want to set up a limited number of customers to pick from, or if you have a  lot of customers or they change frequently just use a text field. However, filtering is a little thicker. You can't directly filter by custom field at the moment but you can use the text search on the board to filter by text in custom fields. In your case it seems like that would still work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **custom fields** for the clients' names: https://blog.trello.com/trello-custom-fields

You can use **Butler** to filter the cards by custom fields.
See this part of the documentation: https://trello.com/c/OR6b2iko/130-custom-fields

Comment: Why the downvotes? Feedback would be appreciated.